# Microsoft XPS Document Writer print driver for Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, automatic-update, xps

I have read that the Microsoft XPS Document Writer printer driver is pre-installed on Windows 7 and Vista. I have an XP machine that also includes the XPS driver and do not remember ever installing it. Does this driver get installed through Windows Automatic Updates or does it require a separate installation?

Answer (score 3):

It is installed along with .net 3.5 or bigger